# If you call a function, that returns an arrow function, as a property of one of your components, will that returned arrow function be rebound?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not want to rebind a function during every re-render. I have a function, that is returning an arrow function (an implicitly binding function), that is called inside a property of another component during the render.

I worry that this may be getting rebound during every re-render. If so, this means that I will be giving my component new properties during every re-render. And if I am, I will have performance concerns.

```
  bar = (foo) => () => {
    // Do some things
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <For
        each="foo"
        of={ foos }
      >
        <ExampleComponent
          baz={ this.bar(foo) }
        />
      </For>
    )
  }
```

I would like to know if `baz` is getting a newly bound function during every single rerender.

Comment: You can put a single `console.log()` right before returning the function in `bar()` to check this.

Comment: What is `foo`? Specifically: Is `foo` an object?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - a new anonymous arrow function is being created each time you call `bar`, which will be on each render.

The most common solution to this problem is to make `bar` a memoized function, so that it returns the same function as the last time it was called with the same value of `foo`. Just don't forget to set a cache size limit on the memoize cache, otherwise your memory usage will never shrink. I suggest using the `memoize-one` module.

Comment: If `foo` is an object, the function cache could be a `WeakMap`, so entries get removed when `foo` is no longer reachable from outside the map.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's true, but only in environments that support `WeakMap`, which may not be all browsers one may be required to support.

Comment: Why not just suggest `React.memo` ?

Comment: Thank you @GregL! That's what I was looking for.